# Multiple IF Statements with Multiple COUNTIFS with Multiple criteria

Tags: if-statement, countif

I'm trying to make a cell display a text value depending on a multiple criteria COUNTIFS statement nested inside multiple IF statements, I have got the first IF(COUNTIFS statement working, but I want to nest another IF statement along with that so the cell can display different text values depending on multiple COUNTIFS, here is what I currently have:

```
IF(
   COUNTIFS(
      B6:B55, "AERONOMAD",
      D6:D55, "",
      F6:F55, "M"
   ),
   FORMULA!A12,
   FORMULA!A10
),
IF(
   COUNTIFS(
      B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",
      D6:D55, "",
      F6:F55, "O"
   ),
   FORMULA!A11,
   FORMULA!A10)
```

I know this part works on its own:

```
IF(
   COUNTIFS(
      B6:B55, "AERONOMAD",
      D6:D55, "",
      F6:F55, "M"
   ),
   FORMULA!A12,
   FORMULA!A10)
```

But when I try and add another IF statement for the same cell it won't allow me; does anyone know a solution for this please?

Comment: I don't think your `IF` statements are correct. Should they not be something like `IF(COUNTIF(…)=3,…)` for example? In excel if you press `Shift+Enter` the formula can be written on multiple lines. Using spacing you should be able to indent the lines, which may make it easier to Understand what long formulas are doing.

Comment: Please ignore the first part of my previous comment, turns out Excel thinks 1 is truthy and 0 is falsey. Have you tried entering `if(…)&if(…)`. The `&` operator will concatenate the formula results. Alternatively use the `concatenate` function.

Comment: unfortunately the &IF combines the two arguments and displays a result whereas I want one cell to display value based on either of these arguments                                                   ```IF(
   COUNTIFS(
      B6:B55, "AERONOMAD",
      D6:D55, "",
      F6:F55, "M"
   ),
   FORMULA!A12,
   FORMULA!A10
)``` ***OR, if the below argument is true, but in the same cell***
```IF(
   COUNTIFS(
      B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",
      D6:D55, "",
      F6:F55, "O"
   ),
   FORMULA!A11,
   FORMULA!A10)```

Comment: I have also tried this ```=IF(OR((COUNTIFS(B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",D6:D55, "",F6:F55, "M"),FORMULA!A12),((COUNTIFS(B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",D6:D55, "",F6:F55, "O"),FORMULA!A11,""),"10\8"))``` but still not getting it right

Answer (score 0):

## How to use `if` Statements

`If` statements are written as `IF(query, when-true, when-false)`.

You can also nest if statements by using more if statements in the true or false arguments.

For example if you want an extra check being made if the condition is false, you can write `IF(condition, if-true, IF(condition2, when-condition2-true, when-condition2-false))`.

## Answer

I think you want to nest the if statements.

The formula below might be what you're looking for.

```
IF(
   COUNTIFS(
      B6:B55, "AERONOMAD",
      D6:D55, "",
      F6:F55, "M"
   ),
   FORMULA!A12,
   IF(
      COUNTIFS(
         B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",
         D6:D55, "",
         F6:F55, "O"
      ),
      FORMULA!A11,
      FORMULA!A10)
   )
```

It checks two conditions (1., 2. below), and the outputs are based on that.

1. Where Rows contain `"AERONOMAD", "", "M"` in columns `B`,`D`,`F`, this will show the text in `FORMULA!A12`.
2. Where Rows contain `"AERO NOMAD", "", "O"` in, this will show the text in `FORMULA!A11`.
3. If neither of the two conditions above are met then it will show `FORMULA!A10`.

**NOTE:**
Please note the spellings of `AERONOMAD` and `AERO NOMAD`. The second formula, as per your question, has a space. Is this intended?

Comment: I have solved this now with the following, I was using the IF function but IF only gives one result for a true value! now I am using IFS and it returns the first true value:                ```=IFS(COUNTIFS(B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",D6:D55, "",F6:F55, "M"),FORMULA!A12,COUNTIFS(B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",D6:D55, "",F6:F55, "O"),FORMULA!A11,TRUE,"10/8")```  Please mark this comment as solved if possible, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Sam.Palf,

It would be best to answer the question yourself, then mark it as correct.

Happy to hear you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this now with the following, I was using the IF function but IF only gives one result for a true value! now I am using IFS and it returns the first true value: 
`=IFS(COUNTIFS(B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",D6:D55, "",F6:F55, "M"),FORMULA!A12,COUNTIFS(B6:B55, "AERO NOMAD",D6:D55, "",F6:F55, "O"),FORMULA!A11,TRUE,"10/8")`